# Find GraphicsPlaceholder in a graphics array in MATLAB 2015

Tags: arrays, matlab, graphics

Recently updated to MATLAB 2015 and it changed the way graphics handles are stored (I think).

I store the handles of various lines on the same graph in a 2d array. In my previous version of MATLAB, any place I didn't fill was just a zero. Now that array is a graphics array and unfilled locations are "GraphicsPlaceholder". Is there any way to search the array to find where they are?

For example, my list of handles is as follows:

```
    P= 

  2x7 graphics array:

  Columns 1 through 6

    Line                   Line                   Line                   Line                   Line                   Line               
    GraphicsPlaceholder    GraphicsPlaceholder    GraphicsPlaceholder    GraphicsPlaceholder    Line                   GraphicsPlaceholder
```

What I'd like to do is search and find which column is filled with lines instead of GraphicsPlaceholder. Ideally, it'd be something like

```
FUNCTION(P) = 

 1     1     1     1     1     1
 0     0     0     0     1     0
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Handle graphics changes were [implemented in R2014b](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/graphics_transition/graphics-handles-are-now-objects-not-doubles.html).

Try this:

```
% Generate some graphics objects
myfigs(1, 1) = figure;
myfigs(1, 2) = figure;
myfigs(2, 2) = figure;

% Generate logic array, placeholders have no properties so fieldnames will
% return an empty cell array
arefigures = arrayfun(@(x) ~isempty(fieldnames(x)), myfigs);
```

This generates:

```
myfigs = 

  2x2 graphics array:

    Graphics               Graphics           
    GraphicsPlaceholder    Graphics
```

And returns:

```
arefigures =

     1     1
     0     1
```

EDIT: A more efficient implementation using [`isa`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isa.html), courtesy of @SamRoberts

```
% Generate some graphics objects
myfigs(1, 1) = figure;
myfigs(1, 2) = figure;
myfigs(2, 2) = figure;

% Check array for placeholders, return a logical array of 'real' graphics objects    
arefigures = arrayfun(@(x) ~isa(x, 'matlab.graphics.GraphicsPlaceholder'), myfigs);
```

Comment: Checking whether the array elements have no properties is a rather indirect way of detecting `GraphicsPlaceholder` objects. Instead, you can just directly test with `isa(x, 'matlab.graphics.GraphicsPlaceholder')`.

Comment: @SamRoberts good point, I was just scanning the descriptions for the various [`is`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/is.html) functions and `isa` didn't quite click into my head for some reason. I blame lack of coffee. Editing now, thank you.

Comment: Thank you both for your help,  both suggestions worked well. 

What would be the advantage to @SamRoberts idea? It does seem more elegant, but would it be faster (I'm only interrogating 3x7 matrices, so computing time isn't the most important in my current implementation.)

Comment: @Helos35 My method is fairly hacky and is reliant on the implementation of `GraphicsPlaceholder` remaining the same (no properties) to function correctly. @SamRoberts' method is much more explicit so it will function correctly as long as `GraphicsPlaceholder` remains a `matlab.graphics.GraphicsPlaceholder` object. It's also much more human readable; without a comment or running the code it's not apparent why my method works. His method is also technically be faster since it's one function call but I'm not sure of the data size where the difference would actually be noticeable.

Answer (score 0):

For R2014b and later, isgraphics(H) might be your solution. In the documentation for the function:
   isgraphics(H) returns an array that contains 1s where the elements
    of H are handles to existing graphics objects and 0s where they are
    not graphics objects or are deleted graphics objects.